# Почему findall выводит только группы?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер, re

Писал небольшой проект для себя - поиск в тексте ссылок. Для этого использовал регулярные выражения и модуль `re` с его методом `findall`.

```
# поиск
pattern = r'https?://[\S]+(\.\S+)+//?(\S//)*'
text = input('==> ')
finded = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(finded)
```

Само регулярное выражение довольно простое, да вот незадача - вывод показывает ТОЛЬКО ГРУППУ

Для примера я передам следующее значение:

```
Вот тестовая ссылка: `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/`
```

И вывод у меня был такой:

```
('.com', '')
```

То есть, программа не выводит полностью совпадения. она предоставляет только группы.

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Заверните всё выражение в круглые скобки, чтобы получилась одна большая группа?

Comment: Да, я так и делаю сейчас, но мне кажется, что решить проблему будет лучше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такова специфика [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> **re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)**

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is
> scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If
> one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
> groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
> group.**
> Empty matches are included in the result.

В качестве решения можно использовать незахватывающие группы (`non-capturing groups`):

```
pattern = r'https?://[\S]+(?:\.\S+)+//?(?:\S//)*'
# NOTE: -----------------> ^^  -------> ^^
```

или же сделать одну группу:

```
pattern = r'(https?://[\S]+(?:\.\S+)+//?(?:\S//)*)'
# NOTE: --> ^ ----------------------------------> ^
```

результат в обоих случаях:

```
In [143]: re.findall(pattern, text)
Out[143]: ['https://ru.stackoverflow.com/']
```